# How could I execute my plugin just in frontend (not in backend)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin, front-end

I don't need my plugin running through wp-admin, including wp-login. How could I prevent it? is_admin works fine but i don't know how to ignore everything related to wp-admin (like wp-login.php).
Thanks.

Comment: What is your Plugin *doing*, and *what hooks are you using* to hook your Plugin into WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Check the requested URI:

```
if(!is_admin()
 && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login.php') === false 
 && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-signup.php') === false) { ... }
```

But it's probably better to use a white-list style:

`if(is_front_page() || is_singular() || is_archive()) { ... }`

These 3 tags should cover pretty much all of the front-end...

Comment: FYI: You can check `$pagenow` to find out the page, it'll look a little nicer than the `$_SERVER` checks..

Comment: It totally depends on what the Plugin is actually *doing*. The query conditionals may or may not be available at the execution point at which the Plugin operates.

Answer (score 0):

```
function start() {
  if( is_admin() == true ) {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/backend/backend-init.php';
  } else {
      require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/frontend/frontend-init.php';
  }
}
  
function runit(){
  add_action('init','start');
}
runit();
```

one will work on the frontend, and the other on the backend respectively.

Comment: That's still just testing is_admin() though, which OP didn't think was enough.

Comment: What's the separate runit function for? Why not just inline the add_action?